# How combine (merge) several number of querysets?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

Can someone say how to **combine (merge) several number of querysets**. The number of querysets are not fixed. I tried next code but it didnt work as I expected. How to fix this problem?

```
first_list = []
for id in ids:
   products = Product.objects.filter(company=id)
   first_list.append(products)

final_list = list(chain(first_list))
```

This code return:

```
[<QuerySet [<1>, <2>]>, <QuerySet [<3>, <4>]>, <QuerySet [<5>, <6>]>]
```

I need:

```
[<QuerySet [<1>, <2>, <3>, <4>, <5>, <6>]>,]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Product.objects.filter(company_id__in=ids)`?

Comment: I dont understand you. What you mean?

Comment: I dont understand what you're actually trying to do, I presume you want to get all products with a company in the set of id's you already have (also assuming company is a FK)

Comment: Here the official doc for the `in` operator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in
`Entry.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 3, 4])` whitout using the `for` statement

Comment: @Sayse Thanks! That's what I was looking for! Can you answer one more time not as comment. I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are just trying to get a list of products matching an existing list, so you can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in), you can then make this a list too if you really need a list of querysets for some reason

```
 products = Product.objects.filter(company_id__in=ids)
 odd_list = [products]
```

The added advantage of this is that this performs a single query to your database instead of `n` queries, it also avoids the need to manually resolve the queryset so that it stays a lazy query and allows you to extend upon this query with further filters as necessary.

Comment: Good answer but I wish you had added the big about why this is so much more peformant than the OP's original attempt too

Comment: @e4c5 - Good point, I've added an additional sentence to expand upon its  capabilities. Thanks